# Develop own "Hash" algorithm

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, math, hash

So I got a **integer variable** between `1 and 10,000`.

I'd like to convert every number to a **`unique!`** hash value that has a fixed length and has a custom charset (includes all alphabetic lowercase and uppercase characters).

So:

- `n=10` could get to `result="AVduujANNiO"`
- `n=4507` could get to `result="BciidEPpaEo"`

---

I do not really know how to develop an algorithm like this so this is all I got so far. I think the algorithm should work but of course I get a integer value as hash - not a alphabetic value. No idea how to fix this and how to pad the result to give it a fixed length.

I really hope somebody is able to help me.

```js
let value = "3325";


var getHash = function(value) {
  let hash = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    let char = value.charCodeAt(i);
    hash = (hash << 6) + char + (char << 14);
    hash=-hash
  } return hash;
};

console.log(getHash(value))
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? It seems pretty wasteful to use an 11 byte string to represent a 14 bit number.

Comment: Easy enough, as long as you have at least 10000 possible hash values to choose from.  That depends on your fixed length and chosen charset.  If your charset includes only the 62 alphanumeric chars then you need at least 3 characters.   Will that do?  Note that this is "base conversion", not "hashing".

Comment: Use your integer to seed a PRNG, then simply use it to fetch N "random" chars from alphabet string.

Comment: Something like `(value * 36 ** 11 / 10000).toString(36).padStart(11, "0")`?

Comment: Why are you trying to make your own hash algorithm? (I hope you're not trying to roll your own crypto). Also [what properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Properties) should your hash function have?

Comment: You wrote "integer between 1 and 10.000"  (ten point zero zero zero) Did you mean "10,000" (ten thousand)?  or did you literally mean "between one and ten".  especially since n=4507 is not between 1 and 10.000.  (Or is that a locale-specific thousands separator I'm not familiar with?)

Comment: What are your requirements for the hash?  Your input space is much smaller than your output space, so you could just append the number to a bunch of junk.  1 -> "AVduujA0001", 2 -> "AVduujA0002", 3 -> "AVduujA0003" etc. and these hashes would still be unique.  So what are you trying to do?

Comment: I wouldn't call this hashing at all. It sounds like you really want to convert to an arbitrary base using arbitrary characters as digits.

Comment: Does your hash have an inverse implementation?  In other words, do you need another function that will receive the string "BciidEPpaEo" as input and return the original 4507 number n?  If so, the random number generator idea is not such a good approach.

Comment: @Wyck In many locales, the "thousands separator" is a period, and the decimal separator is a comma. In much of Europe, for example, the US-English value "12,345.67" would be expressed as "12.345,67".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That's not a particularly good idea, unless you want to implement your own PRNG specifically for this task. Most runtime libraries make no guarantee that their PRNG implementation will remain the same across versions.

Comment: See https://blog.mischel.com/2017/06/20/how-to-generate-random-looking-keys/ for a very simple way to do it.

Comment: The point of a hash is to go from a large input space to a limited output space (fingerprinting). That seems rather unnecessary here, since the input space seems smaller than the output space, or they're roughly equal. The other point of using a hash is to irreversibly, well, *hash* a value and being unable to deduce its original value. That too seems pretty pointless here, since it's trivial to hash all 10,000 numbers and simply store them in a lookup table.

Comment: @JimMischel: true, didn't think of that.

Comment: @JimMischel Wow!  Thanks for pointing that out about European locales. e.g.: `(12345.67).toLocaleString('ca-ES')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hash function that seems to do what you are asking for :) As a bonus, it offers no collisions til 100,000.

```js
function h(n){
  let s = [
    '0101000', '1011010', '0011111',
    '1100001', '1100101', '1011001',
    '1110011', '1010101', '1000111',
    '0001100', '1001000'].map(x => parseInt(x, 2));
    
  let m = parseInt('101', 2);
  
  s = s.map(x => {
    n ^= m;
    m <<= 1;
    return (x ^ n) % 52;
  });

  return s.map(x =>
    String.fromCharCode(x > 25 ? 71 + x : 65 + x)
  ).join('');
}

const s = {};

for (let j=1; j <=10000; j++){
  let hash = h(j);
  
  if (s[hash])
    console.log('Collision! ' + j + ' <-> ' + s[hash]);
    
  s[hash] = j;
}

console.log('Done. No collisions below 10000.');

for (let j=1; j <11; j++)
  console.log(j, h(j));
```